# Encode cp1252 string to utf-8 string in c#

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, cp1252

How I can convert cp1252 string to utf-8 string in c#?
I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
Encoding wind1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
byte[] wind1252Bytes = ReadFile(myString1252);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(wind1252, utf8, wind1252Bytes);
string myStringUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

Comment: `Encoding utf8 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);` code page 1251 is not utf8.

Comment: `Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;`

Answer (score 3):

```
var myGoodString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(
    @"C:\path\to\file.txt",
    Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")
    );
```

A .NET/[CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) `string` in memory cannot be UTF-8. It is just Unicode, or UTF-16 if you like.

The above code will properly read a text file in CP1252 into a .NET `string`.

If you insist on going through a `byte[] wind1252Bytes`, it is simply:

```
var myGoodString = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(wind1252Bytes);
```

---

Since this answer was written, new versions of the framework .NET have appeared which do not by default recognize all the old (legacy) Windows-specific code pages. If `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")` throws an exception with your runtime version, try registrering an additional provider with

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

(may need additional assembly reference to `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll`) before you use `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")`.

See [`CodePagesEncodingProvider` class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider).

Comment: On my machine, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252") throws:     System.ArgumentException: 'Windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method. (Parameter 'name')

Comment: Ah, I have found that .NET Core does not support Windows-1252: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @Froggy On a system where the Windows-specific "code page 1252" is not available, a related (but not quite identical) encoding is the ISO "Latin 1" that you can get with `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")`.

Comment: @Froggy That's pretty lame from .NET Core. Glad I still have Win7 on one machine (Framework), our shops use Sharp cashiers that produce reports in old encoding. Guess I'm not upgrading windows anytime soon, or else we have to buy new cashiers using UTF8 or alike, which would be way more costy.

Comment: You can still get the right `Encoding` by installing the `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` nuget as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37870346/331281

Comment: @Dejan Good point. I have added to the answer.

Comment: @Froggy See above, it is possible to register a new encoding provider.

Comment: @KarlStephen See new info above.